# remove . from email id before @ symbol

Tags: java

I want to remove `.` symbol from email id but java is not allowing me to do this. Someone can help me how to remove `.` symbol.

```
    String test = "email..dd..@abc.com";
    String[] arrOfStr = test.split("@", 2);
    String b = arrOfStr[0];
    System.out.println(b);
    String test1 = b.replaceAll(".", "");
    System.out.println(test1);
```

test1 is print nothing. Is there any way to remove?

Comment: `b.replaceAll(".", "");` is a regex based function which means that "." is any character. you have to escape it `b.replaceAll("\\.", "");`

Comment: you have to use "\\."

Comment: Simply dont use the variant that uses regex, namely `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. The naming is a bit unfortunate, they both replace **all** matches.

Answer (score 4):

You can go this way:

```
String test1 = b.replace(".", "");
```

[more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

or use regex

```
String test1 = b.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll()` takes a regular expression as argument so you need to escape the `.`

```
String test1 = b.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```